# CodeIgniter: Effective Routing

Tags: codeigniter, routes

Say I have a social network which accepts:

short url's using the nickname: e.g. -> www.mynetwork.com/john.doe
256 bit AES hashes: e.g. -> www.mynetwork.com/23fdgfdjhdbfuyviofhedfbncxgersbzc34...

i want to route them to a single controller like 'Profile' wherein:

the short url's version goes to a function like: fetch($nick) in which,
i hash the nick to aes, then make a redirect to call the a function: view($hash)

the view function is the one that actually has the logic for something like displaying that user's profile.

this ensures that whatever the case in which url i choose to visit a profile, whether short url or hash, i always end up getting redirected to the hash url call...

how can i do that? i am thinking it's something to do with routes but i am a little lost on how to go about with it...

to make it short, accessing:
www.mynetwork.com/john.doe redirects to: www.mynetwork.com/23fdgfdjhdbfuyviofhedfbncxgersbzc34 and displays that user's profile

and of course, directly accessing www.mynetwork.com/23fdgfdjhdbfuyviofhedfbncxgersbzc34 will simply display the user's profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not willing to use different URL's for the different functions, like this:

```
www.mynetwork.com/nick/john.doe
www.mynetwork.com/hash/23fdgfdjhdbfuyviofhedfbncxgersbzc34
```

Then, you'll have to write a function that can diffrentiate between a nick and a hash. In your examples, CodeIgniter sees this for both, nick and hash:

```
www.mynetwork.com/{someArg}
```

You could do something like this:

```
www.mynetwork.com/view/nickOrHash
```

The controller:

```
class View extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index($arg)
    {
        if (strlen($arg) < length_of_hash)
        {
            viewByNick($arg);
        }
        else
        {
            viewByHash($arg);
        }
    }

    public function viewByNick($arg)
    {
    }

    public function viewByHash($arg)
    {
    }
}
```

You will also have to edit your URI routing for CodeIgniter so it sends `nickOrHash` as an argument to `index` and does not search for a function called `nickOrHash` under the `view controller` (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

In the above code, replace `length_of_hash` with the length a 256 bit AES hash will always have

EDIT:

Another, more reliable way of determining whether the argument is a nick or hash, could be:

1. You receive argument. Check in database if user with a hash of the argument exists. If exists, call `viewByHash($arg)`
2. If not exists, hash the `$arg`,and check database again if user with the new hash exists. If exists call `viewByHash(newHash)` with the calculated hash.
3. If not exists, `error 404`

Routing:

```
$route['view/(:any)'] = "view/index/$1";
```

If a user requests url `mynetwork.com/view/arg`, codeIgniter will call `index()` method in `view controller` passing the last part of the user's request URL as the argument.

You can change it to something like this, if you want to check by hash directly:

```
$route['view/(:any)'] = "view/viewByHash/$1";
```

If above function fails, then check by username, etc etc

Comment: i was actually thinking close... i planned to make my route with (:any) and route it to viewByNick as initial assumption, then if the search fails, hash it and redirect to viewByHash and try again, and if it still fails, then a 404 is shown or something like profile not found... only thing is, i am not sure what routing rule to place or any other more efficient method of achieving this...

Comment: I would recommend against rerouting so that `mynetwork.com/john.doe` works because that routing would almost certainly break all your controllers. Instead, settle for `mynetwork.com/view/john.doe`. See routing in answer.